# C# mouse recorder needs mouseclick recordings

Tags: c#, mouse, recorder

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tY8wxRGGHKs

following that video and it works, but it does not record/play mouseclicks, once i have that i will modifiy the program so that it can have hotkeys set and random intervals etc, but first i need to be able to record mouseclicks, i've been googling and trying for quite a while now, can't find anything that works/helps :/

code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Mouse_Recorder
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        ListViewItem lv;
        int a;
        int b;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lv = new ListViewItem(Cursor.Position.X.ToString());
            lv.SubItems.Add(Cursor.Position.Y.ToString());
            listView1.Items.Add(lv);
            b++;
        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (a != b)
            {
                Cursor.Position = new Point(int.Parse(listView1.Items[a].SubItems[0].Text), int.Parse(listView1.Items[a].SubItems[1].Text));
                a++;
            }
        }

        private void btnRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            timer2.Stop();
        }

        private void btnPause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer2.Start();            
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            a = 0;
            b = 0;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: It does for me.... did you wire up the events correctly?

Comment: does it record mouse click ? for example if you click on your browser while recording and when you play it back it also clicks in stead of hovering over it? i tested it with a button and a label that goes up by 1 everytime you click on the button, and when i replay it doesn't click the button, just hover over it

Comment: oh ..... mouseclicks...

Comment: i guess you misunderstood? :P